# Should you pronounce the plural 's' after a word that ends with 's'?

Tags: pronunciation

I've always said, for example, "Achilles' shield" as "Achilles-es shield". However, I've noticed others don't pronounce the plural, simply just keep it as "Achilles". Should you pronounce the '-es', or is it not necessary?

Comment: Do you mean plural, or possessive?

Comment: For possessive you pronounce it - For example *the Jones's house* (i.e. the house of the family with the name Jones)  is pronounced /ðə 'ʤoʊnz-ez haʊs/. Some people write *the Jones' house* but still you say /'ʤoʊnz-ez/

Comment: For plural possessive I would probably drop the final s sound, but I don't think it would be wrong to include it. It's a pretty rare combination. For example suppose there are two glasses with a mysterious looking liquid. You might say "I'm not quite sure about these **glasses'** contents." /ˈglæsez ˈkɑːnˌtɛnts/ (the /-ez/ sound is a plural marker, and the possessive 's marker should be written (either as ' or 's) but need not be pronounced in my opinion)

Comment: @Brandin Or you don't pronounce it. Check the answers at the duplicate. Also, there is a tendency to write Jones' for the monosyllabic version. Again, check.

Comment: Generally you do not pronounce an extra "es" for the possessive of a plural.  "Jones's" is a interesting case which seems to contradict this, but really it's the house belonging to the Joneses, not the house belonging to Jones.  For words ending with a S sound, though, there may be no simple rule.  Certainly "Achilles's heel" is typically pronounced without the "es" sound, but "this glass's contents" would typically be pronounced with the "es" sound.